# swap two words in a string php

Tags: php, str-replace

Suppose there's a string "foo boo foo boo" I want to replace all fooes with boo and booes with foo. Expected output is "boo foo boo foo". What I get is "foo foo foo foo". How to get expected output rather than current one?

```
    $a = "foo boo foo boo";
    echo "$a\n";
    $b = str_replace(array("foo", "boo"), array("boo", "foo"), $a);
    echo "$b\n";
    //expected: "boo foo boo foo"
   //outputs "foo foo foo foo"
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [strtr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

From the manual:

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form array('from' => 'to', ...). The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.
>
> In this case, the keys and the values may have any length, provided that there is no empty key; additionaly, the length of the return value may differ from that of str. However, this function will be the most efficient when all the keys have the same size.

```
$a = "foo boo foo boo";
echo "$a\n";
$b = strtr($a, array("foo"=>"boo", "boo"=>"foo"));
echo "$b\n";
```

Outputs

```
foo boo foo boo
boo foo boo foo
```

[In Action](http://3v4l.org/GFr3d)

Comment: As result, all items will be "foo"?

Comment: @Orangepill I havent used `strtr` before. I liked it!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps using a temporary value like `coo.`

sample code here,

```
$a = "foo boo foo boo";
echo "$a\n";
$b = str_replace("foo","coo",$a);
$b = str_replace("boo","foo",$b);
$b = str_replace("coo","boo",$b);
echo "$b\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

First `foo` to `zoo`. Then `boo` to `foo` and last `zoo` to `boo`

```
$search = array('foo', 'boo', 'zoo');
$replace = array('zoo', 'foo', 'boo');
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Answer (score 3):

If as in this example that is the order of your case then using `explode` and `array_reverse` functions can be handy as well:

```
//the original string
$a = "foo boo foo boo";

//explodes+reverse+implode
$reversed_a = implode(' ', array_reverse(explode(' ', $a)));

//gives boo foo boo foo
```

> PS: May not be memory friendly and may not satisfy all cases surrounding *replacement* though, but its simply satisfy the example you gave. :)

Comment: This is a __generic approach__, since it does not require _specific words_ to be known (e.g. `foo`, `boo`), only delimiter (here: ` ` space char) is fixed. Means you simply can change input as `$a = "bar baz";` and it would also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "foo boo foo boo";
echo "$a\n";
$a = str_replace("foo", "x", $a);
$a = str_replace("boo", "foo", $a);
$a = str_replace("x", "boo", $a);
echo "$a\n";
```

note that "x" cannot occur in $a

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
$a = "foo boo foo boo";
echo "$a\n";
$b = str_replace(array("foo", "boo","[anything]"), array("[anything]", "foo","boo"), $a);
echo "$b\n";
```