# How to transliterate non-latin scripts?

Tags: php, localization, iconv

I'm playing around with transliteration in PHP using [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php). Particularly I want to normalise accented characters and Romanize other scripts from UTF-8 to plain ASCII.

While many characters work, (such as `Ž`->`Z`) others are giving odd results or raising errors.

For example, E ACUTE `é` (U+00E9) transliterates to ASCII with a single quote (U+0027) preceding the `e` as if it's trying to represent the diacritic mark I'm trying to get rid of.

```
$utf_8 = "\xC3\xA9"; // <- é
$ascii = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $utf_8 );
// returns "'e", not "e"
```

Non-latin scripts are worse, for example Greek sigma `Σ` (U+03A3) which should transliterate to latin `S` is not recognised at all and raises an error:

```
$utf_8 = "\xCE\xA3"; // <- Σ
$ascii = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $utf_8 );
// Raises notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

I can just about cope with the first one, but how can I transliterate "Σ" to "S", and do this reliably across other scripts that have equivalent characters?

I don't mind generating my own tables if there is a good source that works for most european languages.

Note that I've tried various [collation tables](http://unicode.org/charts/uca/), which are useful for normalising accented latin characters, but they don't work for transliterating between scripts.

Comment: may be able to get some love from strtr. would just have to supply a custom map from one character to another. See here for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850603/swap-two-words-in-a-string-php/17850665#17850665

Comment: it's getting the custom maps I'm worried about. Coding it's not the problem. `strtr` wouldn't work for the multibyte characters in my example anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've not had much luck using `iconv`. It always manages to throw a bunch of notices.

The best luck I've had is with using a custom transliteration table. It's far from perfect but at least you'll feel like you have some solid ground.

I've not found a good single source for transliteration tables. My unfamiliarity with anything but the latin script isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

I've [attempted something similar](https://bitbucket.org/bairwell/namealternatives/src/d3b5161c5d11becee6b3ae3e6b4fbbc6bfb027d4/src/php/Bairwell/NameAlternatives/Utilities/Ascii.php?at=master) - it's mainly based off Doctrine 1 code and isn't perfect: but it seemed to work with all the test data I threw at it.

Comment: Thanks Richy. Yeh, that's a pretty custom looking route. I don't have the problem of cleaning up text in other characters sets or anything, so all I need is one single table with all the right rules. There must be such a thing somewhere.