# PHP: Multibyte unicode convertion

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I've been googling for a bit, also search here but can find a solution.  I'm using PHP. I'm reading a text string (part of X509 cert) and it encoded é to \xC3\xA9 (André => Andr\xC3\xA9).

I've tried [MonkeyPhysics's](http://www.monkeyphysics.com/articles/read/21/decoding_byteescaped_xff_strings_in_php.html) solution:

```
preg_replace("#(\\\x[0-9A-F]{2})#ei", "chr(hexdec('\\1'))", $string);
```

but then I get **AndrÃ©**

I've played around with the *replacement* part;

```
mb_convert_encoding('&#' . hexdec('\\1') . ';', 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')
```

(Also the to_encoding and from_encoding)

I've also looked at [How to transliterate non-latin scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863798/how-to-transliterate-non-latin-scripts) but got no closer.

Surely this should be a standard conversion?

Comment: First at all the e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead (see the PHP manual, it is easy to convert). Before using mb_convert_encoding, try to put `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` in the header of html page that displays the code result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `e` modifier is deprecated in PHP now. You need to use `preg_replace_callback` instead with `/u` modifier for handling unicode strings.

```
$string = 'His nickname was \xE2\x80\x98the Angel\xE2\x80\x99,
which is kind of a clich\xC3\xA9 in my opinion.';

$repl = preg_replace_callback("#(\\\x[0-9A-F]{2})#ui",
           function ($m) { return chr(hexdec($m[1])); }, $string);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
His nickname was ‘the Angel’,
which is kind of a cliché in my opinion.
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, the html page is set to UTF-8 and using this preg_replace_callback works.