# Replacing all words at the same time

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace all words at the same time using str_replace(), but I'm not sure how to do it. Basically, I need change `you` to `me` and `me` to `you` at the same time. How would I do that?

```
<?php

$string = "you me";
$string = str_replace("you", "me", $string);
$string = str_replace("me", "you", $string);

echo $string;

?>
```

**Result:**

```
you you
```

**Need Result:**

```
me you
```

Comment: what you need is the strtr php function check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850603/swap-two-words-in-a-string-php

Comment: $string = strtr($a, array("you"=>"me", "me"=>"you"));

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @frosty please upvote the original post if it helps you, to give credits to the person who given the idea. Just follow the link. Its not my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) can accept array of pairs `'from' => 'to'` to replace as second argument:

```
echo strtr($string, array('you' => 'me', 'me' => 'you'));
```